# The final breath

Tags: riddle

> to eat for a final breath
>
> to judge with a final breath

I have listed two different things that are very much the same. This could be too broad but not likely.

Hint:

> They are linked by the same era, and overall topic.

Another hint:

> something to do with the reniassance

Comment: I would update the post at least to explain what you're looking for. So far I have no idea what this is about. Are you looking for some unifying action / element?

Comment: sort of. Cant get more specific w/o spoling riddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guesses

to eat for a final breath

> [The Last Supper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Supper_(Leonardo_da_Vinci))

to judge with a final breath

> [The Last Judgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Judgment_(Michelangelo))

Reasoning

> Both are famous Renaissance works of art centred around well known aspects of Christianity. Both have Christ as the central figure. Also, both works were made on walls rather than canvas (thanks to Gareth McCaughan for pointing this out) 
> 'The Last Supper' is his final meal before death i.e, his last breath. 'The Last Judgement' represents the Second Coming before the final and eternal judgement of God.

Comment: Seems fairly plausible but if so I think the wording of the question is quite misleading. "For a final breath"? It's not like the Last Supper *caused* Jesus's death or anything. "With a final breath"? That sounds like it should be the *judge's* final breath.

Comment: It might be worth noting explicitly that these two works were both made on walls rather than, say, canvas -- a shared somewhat-unusual feature that may help justify calling them "very much the same".

Comment: Thanks @GarethMcCaughan, I'll add that in. I also agree with on your first point, I still may be wrong.

Comment: all right u got it

Answer (score 0):

Are you a:

> Dragon

to eat for a final breath

> literally when a dragon spits flames over its prey this last exhales his last breath before die

to judge with a final breath

> when a dragon spits flames over the ones who dare to challenge him or hunt him down he literally judges them with a final breath (and burns them down to bones!)

Comment: Did you read the instructions thingie?

Comment: Looks like I misinterpreted the question sorry about that xD

Answer (score 0):

Is the action:

> To choose between 2 identical cups, which one grants immortality while the other poisons you.

To eat for a final breath.

> You drink (sort of eating) a cup for a final breath or one of infinite breaths.

To judge with a final breath.

> The judging you did between the two cups could have been during your final breath.

Comment: Read the *another hint*